# Rails Client Side Validation gem Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I have encountered this peculiar case of the **Client Side Validations gem** not working on a particular form and I just cannot figure out what the problem is.

So here's the form :

```
<% @path = Path.new %>

<%= form_for @path, url: {action: "create"}, validate: true do |f| %>

    <%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: '...' %>

    <%= f.text_area :about, placeholder: '...' %>

    <%= f.text_area :importance, placeholder: '...' %>

    <%= f.text_field :hours_per_day, placeholder: '...' %>

    <%= f.submit "Add Path", class: '...' %>

<% end %>
```

Using this **exact same form** (copy pasting it) on other views does not cause a problem. Only causes a problem on the index view of the Path controller.

There are other forms on the same view meant for the same Path controller but edit action that are working perfectly fine.

Just cannot pinpoint the reason for Client Side Validations not working in this particular situation.

Are there any common problems with the gem that I am missing out on?

Perhaps the answer is really silly but I have spent so much time trying to find out what's the issue that it's not even funny.

Comment: Can you try to remove url: {action: "create"} and see what will happen? What about JS console? Any errors?

Comment: No errors  in the javascript console. I cannot imagine what removing url: {action: "create"} would do. I agree that its unnecessary but I just add it to make it easier to figure out what the form is form amidst a lot of code. Also, as I said, this exact form code works correctly on other pages.

Comment: Just took your advice and tested it out. Removing url: {action: 'create'} doesnt really help.

Comment: Ok. We just tried. It helped me once. Have you tried to search for issue here: https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations/issues 

If not, you can open up a new issue. I'll try continue searching for solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try doing that.